# Browser automatically setting height of content div

Tags: html, css

I have generated a site using wordpress. The pages of the site have content enclosed in a div as follows:

```
<div id="content">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

For reference, here are the css rules:

```
#content {
  background: white url('images/hatch-light.png') repeat;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #333;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #333333;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #333;
  width: 760px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: 15;
}
```

When I view this source I see this reflected. However, using chrome if I inspect the content element, I see that a height is inserted into the div style. I see:

```
<div id="content" style="height: 702px;">
```

The height is the height of my browser window. The problem I am encountering is that the content div no longer encapsulates it's content (for example, the content div has a background style and this background style no longer extends below the height as defined by my browser).

Can anybody tell me how I can prevent the height from being set by the browser?

Comment: If `702` is the height of your viewport, my guess is that there is some JavaScript doing this. (Highly suspect JS, IMO, as the correct way would be to add `style="height:702px"`)

Comment: maybe try adding a height to the css and seeing what happens. if it gets overwritten then it is for sure the js as kevin has stated

Comment: if it is the js, the only way to solve it is by either changing the .js or using an !important in your css to override the inline style.

Comment: @MM Is there an url for your wordpress site, we can see  ?

Comment: try height:auto!important although it is not a good practice

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You are right, a Javascript file is to blame here (it's even called height.js!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Kevin Butcher and the other commenters for pointing this out. The height was being inserted by a piece of javascript (height.js, would you believe). Hence the reason it was visible when inspecting elements, but not when viewing the source.

@chchrist provided a work-around (adding a height:auto!important property to the div) while I figure out how to remove the script from wordpress.